# Display a text input field only if another checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form which posts data to a proccess.php file. In the form i am validating the input. There is a checkbox which asks if a tandem bicycle is used. I want it to display a text input field only if the box is ticked. here is my form code for that porion:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Tandem:</span>
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tandem">&nbsp;
    <input style="visibility:hidden" type="text" name="partnerid" id="partnerid">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Basically if checkbox "tandem" is checked, set text input field "partnerid" `visibility:visible;`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use this code. When the `disabled` property of an input element is `true`, the element cannot be edited. The user usually has an indication that the input field should not be used.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tandem" onchange="this.form.partnerid.disabled=!this.checked" />
```

Explanation of the code:

- `onchange=".."` is triggered when the value of the checkbox changes. This can either occur by clicking, or by using the keyboard. **The click event is NOT sufficient** for this purpose.
- `this.form` from the context of an form element's event listener refers to the form
   All named form elements can then be accessed through `this.form.element_name` or `this.form["element_name"]`.
- When the checkbox is checked (`checked==true`), the input should not be disabled (`disabled=false`). This is done by using a negotiation: `this.form.partnerid.disabled = !this.checked`.

Comment: Thnak you for the great answer. I want it to only change the visibility. Thank you

Comment: The change event in IE doesn't fire until the checkbox loses focus, so  checking with a mouse doesn't make the input visible until focus is shifted. Most browsers will fire a click event if the keyboard is used to check the checkbox, such as Safari, Firefox and IE.

Comment: how would I do it if I have two inputs to be enabled?

Comment: @treblaluch Repeat the statement twice...?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the inputs are in a form, so you can put a click listener on the checkbox that makes the text input visible or not based on whether it's checked or not:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="tandem" onclick="
    this.form.partnerid.style.visibility = this.checked? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  ">
```

It might seem logical to use the change event, but in IE that won't fire until the checkbox loses focus, which is a bit counter intuitive, so use click.